# Regex find work after keyword

Tags: python, regex, string, split, find

Here a String:

```
Sector: id1
    Name: name1
    Data: data1
Sector: id2
    Name: name2
    Data: data2
```

How can I get only the `names`, which are after `Name:` ...
Maybe with regex? But dont know how!?

I need it to get the Names of android virtual device list's output.
I need it to programm an android-programming tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''Sector: id1
    Name: name1
    Data: data1
Sector: id2
    Name: name2
    Data: data2'''
>>> re.findall(r'\bName: (.*)', s)
['name1', 'name2']
```

Comment: can you explain me the syntax pls

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex, just loop over the lines:

```
names = []
for line in openfileobj:
    if line.strip().startswith('Name:'):
        names.append(line.split(':', 1)[-1].strip())
```

where `openfileobj` is an open file object (the return value of a `open()` call), or other sequence of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another thought

```
(Name:)(.*?)(\n)
```

then get group 2

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `re.split`, just builtin `str.split`:

```
In [237]: s='''
     ...: Sector: id1
     ...:     Name: name1
     ...:     Data: data1
     ...: Sector: id2
     ...:     Name: name2
     ...:     Data: data2
     ...: '''

In [238]: [i.split(': ', 1)[1] for i in s.split('\n') if i.strip().startswith('Name:')]
Out[238]: ['name1', 'name2']
```